# Trying to SUM working hours after midnight

Tags: date, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, duration, hour

I have this formula:

```
=ROUNDDOWN(((B1-A1)*24) ; 1)
```

which calculates the duration between two times (B1=end time, A1=start time) and then converts it to decimal.

The current problem I have with this formula is that it is unable to give a correct answer when the end time is past midnight.

How can I improve the formula to make it work when the end time is past midnight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following for a list of dates

```
=INDEX(ROUNDDOWN(((B2:B6-A2:A6+(B2:B6<A2:A6))*24) ; 1))
```

*(**Do** adjust the formula according to your ranges and locale)*

[image]